# Is there a way to induce a PANIC state in Postgres database with a query?

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to test a scenario in which Postgres goes into a PANIC state via a query but I haven't had any luck getting this to work.

Does anyone have a query that would cause such a thing? This is version 12.10.

Comment: AFAIK panic can't be raised by the user. You could [dig through for a bug with that specific version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12-11.html#id-1.11.6.5.5). Does it have to be a panic? What are you using this for?

Comment: Trying to generate a core dump file on RHEL in a sandbox env to make sure a PANIC state from a query will successfully create the file before trying a problem query in production. Data/tables are not easily replicated from that prod schema to sandbox. Trying to avoid running the problem query in prod until we can physically confirm a dump file will generate

Comment: I don't know of any.  If willing you could always compile you own server with some added functionality, or write an extension (in C) that can do it..

Comment: If all you want is to check your system will handle a panic, that sounds like a job for mocking. Otherwise, I agree with jjanes that you can probably get it to panic with the C API. Either directly, or by doing something naughty. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq.html

Comment: You could put the WAL files on a tiny partition and fill the partition, but this does seem like a job for mocking the panic. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/disk-full.html

Comment: Ended up not going through with running the problem query in prod. Never really found a good way to test a PANIC state from a query.